# selecting a particular option from the drop down using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, casperjs

In my web page i have one feature for creating groups. And these groups can be found in drop down menu. Now the problem is when i create a group the index value keeps on changing. Consider the following scenario
Before creating New group i already have 3 groups with the following index value

XYZ = 0
ABC = 1 
QWE = 2

Now i created JKL new group.
and when i open the drop down menu found like this

XYZ = 0
JKL = 1
ABC = 2
QWE = 3

If the index value was constant i could have selected but, since the value is keep on changing randomly. so how to select the newly created group.